# Trying to use Try/Except without an actual loop. Code is stuck on the except portion

Tags: python, discord

Writing a python script that sets up pickup games.  srv.connect() will time out if the IP/RCON are put in wrong and/or the server is down altogether.  I do not want the discord bot to crash just because a server is down so I am trying to use a try/except to keep the bot going.  A person can start a pickup by typing !pickup size 4 servername ... and if srv.connect() can not get a handshake with the server, itll time out and send a message in discord saying it can not find the server.  Then they could do !pickup size 4 servername2 and itll work.  Problem right now is that after doing !pickup size 4 servername it seems stuck on saying the rcon/ip is down even though servername2 should be running just fine.  Any help?

````
if(message.content.startswith('!pickup size')):
        if(pickupActive == 0):
            x = message.content.split()  
            if(len(x) >= 4):  
                pServer = x[3]   
                if(pServer in servers):    
                    srv = Console(host=servers[pServer][0], port= servers[pServer][1], password=servers[pServer][2])
                    try:
                        srv.connect()
                        servercfg = srv.execute("servercfgfile")
                        #print(servers[pServer][3])
                        if (servers[pServer][3] in servercfg): #and (pickupActive == 0)):  #change "server.cfg" to whatever your server configurtion filename is for pickup play.  keep the quotations
                            totalPlayers = [" "] * int(x[2])
                            initialPlayerCount = len(totalPlayers)
                            pickupLeader = message.author.name
                            totalPlayers.insert(playerCount, pickupLeader)
                            totalPlayers.remove(" ")
                            PopulateTable()
                            await message.channel.send("```Pickup Game Starting! " + pickupLeader + " is the leader for the Pickup Game! Come join in! type '!pickup add' to join```")
                            await message.channel.send("```" + msg + "```")
                                

                            pickupActive = 1
                        else:
                            await message.channel.send("`" + servers[pServer][4] + "`")                           
                    except:
                        await message.channel.send("Can not connect to the server for rcon..")
                        srv.disconnect()              
                else:
                    await message.channel.send("`Please specify the size of the pickup and a valid server name..`")
            else:
                await message.channel.send("`Proper formatting not used, please say !pickup size # server (Example: !pickup size 3 nwo)`")
        else:
            await message.channel.send("`Already a pickup game in progress, please add up to the current pickup game..`")
````

Comment: what error is catched on the except block ?

Comment: There really wasnt an error.. in truth it did exactly what it was suppose to do up to that point which is, if the rcon password was wrong (or the server was down/wrong IP), it went to the exception, problem is it never LEFT the exception which could just be my amateurism at play here.  I just ended up using os.execv on the exception and restarting the script fresh as a solution